# Testing countdown timer with cypress

Tags: testing, cypress

I have a web app that in one part of it a timer needs to count 1 minute. Now for doing the end to end testing I am using Cypress, In Cypress documentation I found cy.clock and cy.tick. The documentaion is vague to me. So which of these should I use for testing a countdown timer?

Answer (score 0):

Cypress `cy.clock()` has a "freeze frame" effect on timers in your app.

The passing of time can be controlled with `cy.tick()` to move the time frame on.

It makes your test run much quicker than waiting for a `timeout` to actually happen.

```js
cy.clock();                                // take control of timers
cy.get('#timer-btn').click();

cy.tick(30000);                            // move time frame +30 seconds
cy.get('.btn').should('be.enabled')        // button still available

cy.tick(60100);                            // move time frame +60.1 seconds

cy.get('#timer').should('have.text', 'TIME IS UP, your score is: 0');

cy.get('.btn').should('be.disabled')       // button is not available
```

This only works if the timer is using the `setInterval` function.